# What is SIGUSR2 used for in the TCL interpreter?

Tags: tcl, signals, user-defined

I'm getting a **user defined signal 2** error from the tcl interpreter. What does the tcl interpreter use this particular signal for? In other words, what does it mean if the tcl interpreter send me a user defined signal 2?

It is an elapsed timeout? Is it lack of memory? Where can I find out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tcl does not use this signal for itself in any way. It does not generate it, it does not set a special handler for it, and it does not provide any scripted way to respond to it.
If you are using TclX or Expect, you can generate it with `kill` and define your own handler with `signal`. But you have to do those for yourself, nothing does it for you.

IIRC, some memory managers use signals as part of how they operate. I claim no expertise in the matter.

Comment: I guess I must be getting it from somewhere else than.. But where? This is the most obscure problem I've ever had! Thanks for eliminating one theory.

Comment: @Shawn: Sorry I couldn't help more, but I just don't know. I did grep the source code though; Tcl doesn't ever send a signal to anything, and the only one it touches in terms of handling is SIGPIPE (which it turns off, as it doesn't want all that low-value noise).